# How to split string and remove duplicate and concatenate second part of string

Tags: xml, xslt

I was trying to split the following string in XSLT and remove duplicate and concatenate the second part of the string in following manner.

```
<items>Vegetable|tomoto|,vegetable|potato,fruit|apple,fruit|orange,fruit|kiwi</items>
```

I was able to split by ',' and '|' and create individual tags , but I need to create an xml with the following format by removing duplicate 'vegetable' and 'fruit'

Expected Result

```
<category>vegetables</category>
<subcategory>tomoto,potato</subcategory>
<category>fruits</category>
<subcategory>apple,orange,kiwi</subcategory>
```

Thanks
Rahul HR

Comment: Please post attempted XSLT and ask a *specific* question regarding your attempt (i.e., error, undesired result). Also, your expected result is not well-informed since it does not have a root. FYI - tomato is technically a fruit.

Comment: Also include what version of xslt. That makes a huge difference when it comes to processing text with xslt.

Comment: @Parfait It depends: to a botanist, a *tomato* is a fruit; to a dietician (and also to a US customs officer), it is a vegetable. A *tomoto*, OTOH, could be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your input actually looks more like:

```
<items>vegetable|tomato,vegetable|potato,fruit|apple,fruit|orange,fruit|kiwi</items>
```

(i.e. with all the categories listed using the same letter case, and without redundant  delimiters) and that your processor supports XSLT 2.0, you could get the expected result using:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="tokenize(items, ',')" group-by="substring-before(., '|')">
    <category>
        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
    </category>
     <subcategory>
        <xsl:value-of select="for $str in current-group() return substring-after($str, '|')" separator=","/>
    </subcategory>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:variable name="items">
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(items, ',')">
        <item cat="{substring-before(., '|')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '|')"/>
        </item>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:for-each-group select="$items/item" group-by="@cat">
    <category>
        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
    </category>
    <subcategory>
        <xsl:value-of select="current-group()" separator=","/>
    </subcategory>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Note that the result does NOT group category and subcategories together.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It is answered my query.

Answer (score 0):

Or a bit more compact in XSLT 3:

```
  <xsl:template match="items">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select=". => tokenize(',')" group-by=". => substring-before('|') => lower-case()">
        <category>{current-grouping-key()}s</category>
        <subcategory>
          <xsl:value-of select="current-group() ! substring-after(., '|')" separator=","/>
        </subcategory>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

It is not clear whether you want the `xsl:copy`. The use of the text value template `<category>{current-grouping-key()}s</category>` assumes you declare `expand-text="yes"` for the stylesheet (or at least the template).